# Cups entity too large on docker

Tags: debian, cups

I need to use cups and cups-pdf in a docker container. I use Debian as base image and I install cups and printer-driver-cups-pdf.

When I try to install the "pdf printer" I have the error

> Request Entity Too large

Nothing in logs

```
lpadmin -p cups-pdf -v cups-pdf:/ -E -P /usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd
```

How could I debug my problem?

I need something to print PDF in a docker container on my server. Is there any other way?

Comment: does the pool directory exists?

Comment: Yes. I have cups and cups-pdf in /var/spool